# make the first item in a list box the focus

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

I am using a range of items to populate a drop down list.  Here is the code:

```
 Dim s As String, r As Integer, nr As Integer, wr, v
    Set wr = Sheets("Role Plays").Range("A2:A40")
    nr = wr.Rows.count
    For r = 1 To nr
        v = wr(r, 1)
         If InStr(s, v & ",") = 0 Then
         s = s & v & ","
    End If
    Next
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    With Sheets("Data View").Range("D2").Validation
         .Delete
         .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=s
    End With
```

It works nicely except I want the focus to be on the first item in the list after the list is created.

thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: `Sheets("Data View").Range("D2").Select`?

Comment: thanks Chrismas007, that selects cell d2 where the list lives but does not select the first item in the list as the focus.  Changing an item in the list launches another macro.  If the user sees the option they want, they will not select it and the macro won't run.  the first item in the list is "Select a Role Play" which will force them to make a choice and thence run the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will set the value of the cell:

```
Sheets("Data View").Range("D2").Value = "Select a Role Play"
```

Comment: that's it thanks,  I had assumed that if i put something in the cell using that method it would overwrite the items in the dropdown so I had not tried it.